# MongoDB: Cannot Stop Balancer

Tags: mongodb, database-administration

I am trying to upgrade my mongo from 2.6 to 3.0. When I try to upgrade mongos, I get an error:

```
error upgrading config database to v6 :: caused by :: balancer must be stopped for config upgrade
```

Since my mongos is already down, I tried to stop balancer from config server and I get the following error:

```
Error: not connected to a mongos :
```

Is there a workaround to stop the balancer and upgrade mongos?

Comment: db.locks.find( { _id : "balancer" } ).pretty() check the balance block status.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start a mongos process up just to disable the balancer.

The required upgrade steps for a sharded cluster are listed in the release notes at https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/